# Is there a way to call the get instead of post using dropdownlist and onchange?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here’s what I’ve been trying:

```
        @Html.DropDownList("DropDownValue", new SelectList(ViewBag.sellectedSubjects, "text"), "select one", new { onchange = "this.form.action='/Profile/Edit';this.form.submit();" })
```

This works but it calls the POST instead of the Edit GET as I would like.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're changing the action, why not also change the method?

```
new { onchange = "this.form.method='GET';this.form.action='/Profile/Edit';this.form.submit();" })
```

Or change it in the Razor/HTML (I'd say this is preferable, since it's generally cleaner to make the HTML correct to begin with rather than hacking at it with Javascript):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Get)) 
{
    // ...
}
```